# Java sorted Array collection to String

Tags: java, string, arraylist

```
ArrayList<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<Integer>()
```

factors = `[1, 183, 3, 61]`;

`Collections.sort(factors);` is => `[1, 3, 61, 183]`

How can I turn `[1, 3, 61, 183]` to this => `"1 3 61 183"`

Comment: is representation the only difference? when? how are you trying to access the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Collections.sort(factors)` (or [`factors.sort(null)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-)), you can use a `Stream` to sort and then collect it to `String` using `Collectors.joining`.

```
String result = factors.stream()                           // iterate all the list
                       .sorted()                           // make it sorted
                       .map(Number::toString)              // convert Number to String
                       .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));  // collect them to String
```

The most confusing parts for you might be `map` and `collect`, let me explain more in detail:

- `map(Number::toString)` is the same as `map(n -> n.toString())` which calls `toString` method to each of the element iterated through. It results from `Stream<String>` in `Stream.
- `collect(..)` takes all the `Stream` as is and using a `Collector` creates an output from the streamed elements. It might be a `Map`, `List` or any object `T` - it depends on the `Collector`.
- `Collectors.joining(" ")` is a collector, that requires `Stream<String>` and concatenate elements together with the delimiter, which is one empty space in our case `" "`.

Comment: Consider marking this or any other answer which you consider as the most helpful as accepted - it says the community that the issue has been resolved.

Comment: That's not sorted though.

Comment: @Nikolas if you have time, can you please walk me through your code? It works but I do not fully understand it. You can also send me links so I can read up on this. Thank you.

Comment: @fabtree: See the edit - there is a short explanation in my answer included :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use call `toString` of `ArrayList` and remove brackets like this,

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> factors = Arrays.asList(1, 183, 3, 61);
        String arrayString = factors.toString();
        System.out.println(arrayString.substring(1, arrayString.length() - 1).replace(",", ""));
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'toString(java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Integer>) this is the error I get and Arrays.toString(factors) factors is underlined with red in intelliJ

Comment: @fabtree thats because you were using an ArrayList and first I thought you were using a int[] type array. I have updated my code. Please check it :)

Comment: You forgot to remove commas separating the elements.

Comment: @Nikolas My bad... Thanks for showing. I have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

The following code sample should accomplish this. We are declaring a new array to hold the string values (Setting it equal to the same size as the integer array), and filling out with the string values of the integers.

```
String myStringArray[] = new String[factors.length];

for (int i = 0; i < factors.length; i++){
    myStringArray[i] = String.valueOf(intArray[i]);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myStringArray));
}//end for
```

Answer (score 0):

You may convert any object to string directly using `toString()` method of that object.
here you can manipulate string functions as per your requirement.

replace brackets with double quotes as below

```
String s = factors.toString();
s=s.replace("[", "\"");
s=s.replace("]", "\"");
```

or you may only remove square brackets using substring mathod of string and make it useful. as below

```
String s = factors.toString();
s=s.substring(1,s.length()-1);
```

remove comma using below method

```
s=s.replace(",","");
```

try it , may it will help you.

Comment: You forgot to remove commas separating the elements.